# Laravel and Eloquent - applying different filters

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm feeling stuck. :(

I want to be able to execute different SQL query, depending on the selected filters in my form:

```
//My initial query without any filters is this:
$dbQuery="SELECT * FROM \"interactions\" WHERE \"user_id\" = ".Auth::user()->getAttribute('id');
//Then depending on the selected filters the query may be any combination of the following:
if (request('contact_id')) $dbQuery.=" AND \"contact_id\" = ".request('contact_id');
if (request('product_id')) $dbQuery.=" AND \"product_id\" = ".request('product_id');
if (request('type')) $dbQuery.=" AND \"type\" LIKE \"%".request('type')."%\"";
if (request('description')) $dbQuery.=" AND \"description\" LIKE \"%".request('description')."%\"";
if (request('date')) $dbQuery.=" AND \"date\" >= ".request('date');
```

I have a class called "Interaction" which extends the Eloquent model and I need to be able to execute the above query or represent the same logic through it.

Any ideas on how I can achieve that will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:
Thanks to Brice (my personal hero today), here is what did the trick for me:**

```
$query = Interaction::where('user_id', Auth::id());
$contact_id = request('contact_id');
$product_id = request('product_id');
$type = request('type');
$description = request('description');
$date = request('date');
if ($contact_id) $query->where('contact_id', $contact_id);
if ($product_id) $query->where('product_id', $product_id);
if ($type) $query->where('type', 'like', "%".$type."%");
if ($description) $query->where('description', 'like', "%".$description."%");
if ($date) $query->where('date', '>=', $date);
$interactions = $query->get();
return view('interactions.index',compact('interactions'));
```

Comment: What specifically are you having troubles with in achieving this? What have you tried? On a side note, currently your query leaves you vulnerable to injection issues - your should use bindings in your query instead of putting the data values directly in the query.

Comment: Hi, zbee! I'm VERY new to Eloquent and it is kind of blurry to me. I've gone through a lot of articles and documentation but can't seem to find the right functions to represent the above logic. Any directions will be appreciated! I'm aware of the problem with the injections but this is the least of my concern right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using the eloquent query builder for this.

For example:

```php
$query = Interaction::where('user_id', Auth::id());

$contact_id = request('contact_id');
$product_id = request('product_id');
$type = request('type');
$description = request('description');
$date = request('date');

if ($contact_id) {
    $query->where('contact_id', $contact_id);
}

if ($product_id) {
    $query->where('product_id', $product_id);
}

if ($type) {
    $query->where('type', 'like', "%$type%");
}

if ($description) {
    $query->where('type', 'like', "%$description%");
}

if ($date) {
    $query->where('date', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date));
}

$results = $query->get();
```

If you have a lot of results, you may want to use pagination instead of fetching all results at the same time as shown above.

Comment: Thank you, Brice! Pagination will be the next step... :) One more question: This way, when the user data passes through Eloquent, do I have to worry about the injection issues?

Comment: @Kalo 
Nope, you're safe when using the query builder because under the hood Laravel uses parameter bindings.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#introduction

"The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings."

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, Brice! You saved me a lot of headaches. I did a few tweaks in your code and everything is working fine now. I've accepted your answer and edited my question with the working code. :)

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `->when()` method [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
$results = Interaction::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->when($contact_id, function ($query) use ($contact_id) {
        $query->where('contact_id', $contact_id);
    })
    ->when($product_id, function ($query) use ($product_id) {
        $query->where('product_id', $product_id);
    })
    ->when($type, function ($query) use ($type) {
        $query->where('type', 'like', "%$type%");
    })
    ->when($description, function ($query) use ($description) {
        $query->where('type', 'like', "%$description%");
    })
    ->when($date, function ($query) use ($date) {
        $query->where('date', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date));
    })->get();;
```